# Is it possible identify hardware Issues through BIOS?

Tags: windows, bios, peripherals

I trying to find why my notebook is not working keyboard and mouse, both only work using USB peripheral. 
After installing a new operating system (WIN 10), it did not identify the wireless network.

Comment: Open MSINFO32.exe (WinKey, Run, MSINFO32. The Computer model is there. Open the categories to see network components. You need to work through the detail but it is all there

Comment: Anyway I can make a diagnose through BIOS right? I need an OS installed

Comment: Different BIOS have different presentations. You should be able to find major components.  You can also look in Device Manager (Control Panel) as that also tells you what the Network Components are (NIC model type).

Comment: "Is it possible identify hardware Issues through BIOS?" Only if there is hardware diagnostics in the bios. Be sure wireless is enabled in the bios if it has this ability, if not see if there is a wireless switch externally.